# Fixed Layout EPUB where each page has a different size

Tags: html, xhtml, epub, epub3

I am trying to create an Epub file which has a fixed layout but not each page should have the same dimensions. Some pages should landscape others portrait. Can this be achieved with EPUB 3?

What do I have to change in the opf-file, stylesheets and/or each xhtml of a page to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using different `/manifest/itemref/@properties` for different layout. See below example:

---

```
<spine>
   ...
   <itemref idref="page01" properties="rendition:orientation-portrait"/>
   <itemref idref="page02" properties="rendition:orientation-landscape"/>
   ...
</spine>
```

---

Please note `@properties` could only be used for `epub3`.